# How to set up a button in Access to synchronize everything from Access to SQL Server?

Tags: ms-access

I have created a link from access to the SQL server, but we also want to create a button in Access entry form so it would be easier to synchronize our data from access to SQL server. Already have a corresponding table in the SQL server and the link. Initially, I thought it would be straightforward to add a button on the Access form, to add a button and create a macro event, but my coworker said it would be complicated. So can anyone help to show me what I am expecting in this assignment as I am not able to find useful information so far?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. As it stands, your question is too broad... please provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) showing what you have tried and what exactly is the issue you are experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

A truly linked table does not need synchronization. It only exists in one location. For example: If you create a table in SQL and then make a linked table in Access then the changes in Access are written directly to the SQL table. The Access table doesn't contain anything but the link. This would be the correct set up.

Comment: Thanks, @HackSlash,  as I already have the link in my access and I can see all changes made in access have been reflected back in SQL Server table.  But they are asking for a  button. Initially I thought I just need to 
create a button and set up macro event in it and
 then they told me it is more complicated than that and I still have no idea what is the complexity.The button triggers a macro event to run some code, which would be a truncate and replace the data in your access table.  Thank you so much!

Comment: It's not clear if you still need help or not. If you do, please edit your question to be more specific. If they are asking for a sync button on a linked table you could honestly make a button that does nothing just to make them happy. I would only resort to this after explaining that linked tables don't need a sync button.

Comment: Hey @HackSlash.  Appreciate your help. I think I might not be clear what to do, but I will come back later to elaborate my questions better as I am pretty new to Access and I need to talk with my clients more about what they want.  But I understand your point that if I do need to update my records, I might need to put some stored procedures there in the button.  Anyway, Thanks a lot.